# Detecting the outer circle using Hough Circle Transform

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

When i apply `houghCircle` to my image it always detect the inner circle, i spent much time tuning the parameters but the result always the same.

My procedure is convert image into `HSV` color space then `Threshold` on a red color to get a `binary` image then applying `houghCircle`.

**My Image**

[image: Original]

**After Hough Circle**

[image: After Hough]

**Code**

```
Mat hsv = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(bgr, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV); //BGR to HSV

Mat mask1 = new Mat();
Mat mask2 = new Mat();

Core.inRange(hsv, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), mask1);
Core.inRange(hsv, new Scalar(160, 100, 100), new Scalar(179, 255, 255), mask2);

Mat hsvThres = new Mat();
Core.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2, hsvThres);
 //
Mat circles = new Mat();

int iCannyUpperThreshold = 1; //100
int iMinRadius = -1;   //20      //90
int iMaxRadius = -1;  //400 //150-1000
int iAccumulator = 1;//300

Imgproc.HoughCircles(hsvThres, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, //2
         1.0, hsvThres.rows() , iCannyUpperThreshold, iAccumulator, iMinRadius, iMaxRadius);

if (circles.cols() > 0)
    for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) 
        {
        double vCircle[] = circles.get(0,x);

        if (vCircle == null)
            break;

        Point pt = new Point(Math.round(vCircle[0]), Math.round(vCircle[1]));
        int radius = (int)Math.round(vCircle[2]);

        Core.circle(bgr, pt, radius, new Scalar(0,255,0), 4, 8, 0);
       }
```

**NOTE** 
**1)** When i changed `minRadius` to `90` it detected the outer one instead of the inner but i want smth generic that will work for images/signs not only for this test image.

**2)** If i converted the Original image into `Grey` space instead of `HSV` it detects the outer rather than the inner, but also it is not my case since i have to convert my image into `HSV` to do `Thresholding`.